# SBS Domain loosing file access privileges

Tags: windows-7, windows-sbs, folder-redirection

We had a SBS 2008 which was working and stable on an office (buiness centre) network. We used a subnet mask 192.168.X.Y. We moved to a larger office and needed to have a subnet mask 192.168.A.B Now windows (7) comes up with (something like) "windows has dectected an unauthorised attempt to access the network" and after logging on for a few hours, drive mapping and access are lost. Also the redirected, synced desktop folder access is occasionally disabled. Seems to happen on ip4 and ip6 machines although ip6 seems worse?! Our PCS are running a mix of 32 and 64 bit windows 7. Cant be the first to have this problem. A list of things to check would be a good start...please

Comment: Has your DHCP and DNS been fully updated to reflect the IP changes?

Comment: I believe we have updated DHCP and DNS and flushed the cache and updated (removed the old entry) for the hosts file. I will check again when I get back into the office. Thanks